# subclasses common methods implemented in abstract superclass with different constructors

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I know that this has been discussed already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602879/superclass-common-method-implementation) but i have something to add up to that question. I need to make an abstract class called AbstractGraph, and it has to be extended by two types of graph implementations: one uses a matrix, the other one uses lists.

So far i have something like this:

```
abstract class AbstractGraph implements Graph {

    public void removeAllEdges(){
        //implementation here 
    }

}
```

and the subclasses:

```
public GraphMatrix(){
    GraphMatrix()
    {
        //implementation for matrix type 
    }
}

public GraphList(){
    GraphList()
    {
        //different implementation for lists type
    }
}
```

both implementations would have the same `removeAllEdges()` method written exactly the same, so i guess it has to be placed in the abstract class. My question is, how do i get to use references to `this` from inside the abstract class ? Do i have to fill the implementations with getters and setters ? If so, what would be the benefit of using a single implementation of a method for two (or more) subclasses.

Comment: What do you mean "written exactly the same"?

Comment: @DavidWallace copy paste code, now you understand ?

Comment: Yeah, I tend to prefer helping people who aren't sarcastic when I ask for clarification.  Bye for now.

Comment: @DavidWallace i was really not sarcastic and i apologize if my comment seemed so. I was trying to point out that i really copy pasted the code, i mean it's exactly exactly the same for both implementations, because i use on both implementations a list of nodes and a list of edges for easier management.

Comment: OK, but if the two implementations have fields of different types, for example, one has a `List` called `vertices` and the other has a `Set` called `vertices`, and you call a method that has the same name in each of those classes; then it's not the same method, and the fact that it has been copied and pasted from one class to the other is irrelevant.  A call to `remove` in the `List` class is not the same as a call to `remove` in the `Set` class.  On the other hand, if a field from each subclass has the same type and the same meaning, then it could be replaced by a field in the superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same code for removeAllEdges as long as it does not depend on the underlying structure (e.g., the matrix or the list) or the functionality is implemented by encapsulated methods that use the underlying graph structure (e.g., getters, setters, and other common methods that you may need). In my perspective, the latter methods would be the abstract methods of this class, since they need to be implemented according to the underlying graph structure.

One of the benefits is code reuse. You write once, and use it in every graph implementation. In your case you have two graph classes, but you may end up having multiple representations for graphs depending on your application. Writing general methods is a nice way of saving time spent in coding, and it also helps you to maintain your code in a more efficient and organized way. The debugging is also easier!!

Comment: So i should write the more (common) code i can in the abstract class and leave the implementations only for differences between the two ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.Every method depending on the underlying structure of the graph should be implemented in subclasses.If these methods are going to be present for every subclass, the header should be declared in the abstract class: 

    /*abstract class*/
    public int getNumberVertex();

    /*subclass1*/
    @override
    public int getNumberVertex(){ 
        //depends on your graph
    }

If your method only uses common methods you can just implement your removeAllEdges method in the abstract class and you it will be implemented in every subclass, just writing it once :)

Comment: I understood that but i mean, do i have to somehow split the code between the abstract and subclasses? A short example: both implementations use two `ArrayLists` one for edges and another one for nodes. A method `printGraph()` that uses only these two array lists should all three reside inside the abstract class ? Can a subclass modify protected attributes inside the superclass?

Comment: If the ArrayLists are present in all subclasses and they have the same behaviour, then the declaration of the ArrayLists and the printGraph code can be placed in the abstract class.

Comment: That's the thing ! Thank you !